# Creating endpoints inside an endpoint in fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi

suppose there as an audio server, you can upload Songs, podcasts, or Audiobook. So in the create endpoint i have created 4 endpoints,  so i have put an condition if the audio_type is a song, return all audio of that type but unfortunately this return null

```
@app.get('/audio/{audio_type}')
def show_all(audio_type):
    if audio_type == "Songs":
        @app.get("audio/song")
        def all(db: Session = Depends(database.get_db)):
            songs = db.query(models.Song).all()
            print("songs =  ", songs)
            return songs


    elif audio_type == "podcast":
        @app.get('audio/podcast')
        def all(db: Session = Depends(database.get_db)):
            podcast = db.query(models.Podcast).all()
            return podcast

    elif audio_type == "audiobook":
        @app.get('audio/audiobook')
        def all(db: Session = Depends(database.get_db)):
            audiobook = db.query(models.Audiobook).all()
            return audiobook
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f' {audio_type} - audio type is not valid')
```

Comment: Why would you want to create an endpoint inside of an endpoint when clearly your if/else condition is doing all the lifting for you?

Comment: Wouldn't be better to have 3 endpoins? /audio/songs, /audio/podcast and /audio/audiobook?

Answer (score 2):

You are defeating the purpose of an API with your implementation.
For such an implementation, try passing the value as an argument to your API and based upon that you can bifurcate the flow.

```
def all(db: Session = Depends(database.get_db), audio_type):
    if audio_type == "Songs":
        songs = db.query(models.Song).all()
        print("songs =  ", songs)
        return songs
    elif audio_type == "podcast":
        podcast = db.query(models.Podcast).all()
        return podcast
    elif audio_type == "audiobook":
        audiobook = db.query(models.Audiobook).all()
        return audiobook
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f' {audio_type} - audio type is not valid')
    
@app.get('/audio')
def show_all(audio_type: str):
    return all(Depends(database.get_db), audio_type):
```